# Utilization Tool, MS-Project alternative, Resource Controlling Tool

Tags: project-management, utilization

i'm looking for a alternative Program to control my resources, collabrators and projects.

I dislike MS-Project, maybe alternative MS-Project specialisized on Ressource Controlling.

Does anyone have such an Magic-Tool? (:

Open-Source / Freeware preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you need regarding "Resource Controlling"?
[RationalPlan](http://www.rationalplan.com/) is an alternative to MS Project.

Comment: What i mean with Resource Controlling is, Overview of the plant utilization, hour rate per Collaborator, nice reports allover. Projects should not be in foreground, Collaborators should be.